# How to remove the border on broken/unloaded images in email clients such as Outlook 2007?

Tags: html, email

Before a user has chosen to view images in an HTML email there is a grey border around them. Is there any way to hide or remove this border? I have tried the following with no success:

```
<img width="9" height="28" src="button-right.gif" border="0" style="border: none;" />
```

This affects all or most email clients e.g. Outlook 2007, Entourage, Gmail, iOS 5.

I'm starting to think there's no way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I build HTML emails as part of my job. This is how i would normally lay out an image:

```
<img style="display:block;" src="Images/main-image.jpg" height="304" width="593" title="title-text" alt="alt-text" border="0" />
```

I would remove: `style="border: none;"`

Otherwise my suggestion would be that the image has a grey border. If you want to send me the entire email and ill have a look send me a link to download it.

Answer (score -1):

Use css. set the image's style to`border: 0` and `outline:0`